# jQuery add checkbox value to URL without redirect / refresh

Tags: jquery, url, append

I would like to add checkbox values to URL without refresh / redirect the page.
I have my filter that works perfectly with AJAX but this is not SEO friendly because the URL doesn't change while changing the checkboxes.

So if i have for example a checkboxes like these:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
```

And URL is now www.mydomain.com/transport.php?
And jQuery should append vehicles=Bike,Car
Or just one of these
If checkbox isn't checkhed the value to append would just be ''

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [window.location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) property, would be something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>

<script>
$('input[type=checkbox').click(function(){
        window.location.hash = 'vehicles=' + $(this).val();
    });
</script>
```

I am assuming you have the url like www.mydomain.com/transport.php?

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for the website is ready, thanks a lot!